# Как я могу добавить одно значение в несколько словарей в Python

Tags: python

Например у меня есть 100 словарей. Как я могу добавить ко всем этим словарям одно и тоже значение?

Comment: Самый главный вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Приведите свой код и опишите, что бы Вы хотели видеть на входе и на выходе Вашей программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
dictionaries = [dict(), dict()]

for dictionary in dictionaries:
    dictionary['x'] = 10

print(dictionaries)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если эти словари находятся в массиве то так:

```
arr = массив где лежат словари
for dict_ in arr:
    dict_[какой-то ключ] = какое-то значение
```